# Yii2 - Amazon Product API Integrate

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Hi am new to Yii2 and have to integrate with amazon to get their products to advertise on mysite ... Anyone please explain how to do it .. Am having the key and client secret.Please let me know how to do this as step by step.

Comment: Just googl it! https://github.com/wilianto/yii2-amazon-product-api

Comment: @Konstantin Ya ,I went through it .But they are just giving the Files, am unable to get the process that how to do it

Comment: @Pila try the module by yourself and then post if you have any problem or ask a more specific question.